# ajax control toolkit requires asp.net ajax 4.0 scripts

Tags: ajax, controls, toolkit

I face the following error:

`AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll`

I am using ToolScriptManager in my page, also I am using VS2012 and when I created my project it was targeting .NET 4.5. However my Ajax control dll was compatible with .NET 4.0 and hence my ajax controls were not working. I then changed the version of my project from 4.5 to 4.0 from the properties of the solution and then it started working. However recently some settings in my project changed and I am getting the error again.

I am having no clue of what went wrong.

Once again I am using VS 2012, .NET Framework changed from 4.5 to 4.0 in my project and am using Ajax control toolkit 4.0

Answer (score 0):

See if it is working after deleting "Microsoft.ScriptManager.MsAjax.dll" file in /bin folder. Also, don't forget to delete the line asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" in Site.Master file.